# Is there any option in Croogo CMS to add my own form and validation functionality?

Tags: content-management-system, croogo

Is there any option in Croogo CMS to add my own form and validation functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Croogo is built on top of CakePHP, so you can of course add your own Models (with validation), Forms, etc.

Read:

- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models.html
- http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html